# If there isn't something like this in Drupal then it should be added: translating object properties

Tags: php, drupal

Digging into the api looking for methods to translate a property of a category term I could only find methods that take a string as the param, but what happens when I have the id of the object which property I want to translate? I'd like to be able to just pass this id and get the translated string (if exists). I achieved this with a relatively simple query:

```
   function translate_term_description($tid) {
    $result = db_query('SELECT term_data.tid, term_data.description, locales_target.translation 
                        FROM {term_data} 
                        left join ({i18n_strings}, {locales_target}) 
                        on (term_data.tid = i18n_strings.objectid and i18n_strings.lid = locales_target.lid) 
                        where term_data.tid = %d', $tid);

    $term_data = db_fetch_object($result);

    // If a translated string is available return that, otherwise return back the untranslated description
    return !is_null($term_data->translation) ? $term_data->translation : $term_data->description;
}
```

I just needed the description and I'm just using this function in a context where's it's assumed that the target language is the non-default. Still, it can be expanded to take both the target language and the term property as params.

So what do you think? Should something like this exist on Drupal, or does it have it already (if so, please point me where) ?

Comment: This is more like a discussion which should be on drupal.org rather than a programming question.

Comment: It's actually both, I'd like to know if Drupal already has something like this. And no, I feel more confortable in this community than in Drupal's forums so please bear with it. Thanks tho for taking the time to let us know your opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about [i18ntaxonomy_translate_terms](http://api.lullabot.com/i18ntaxonomy_translate_terms) from [Internationalization](http://drupal.org/project/i18n) ?

Comment: Ya, this would be the closest to what I was talking abouut.

Answer (score 1):

For terms and other items you can use [`tt()`](http://api.lullabot.com/tt), if you have i18n installed. This is not part of Drupal core, but is a contrib module.

The `tt()` function has become a wrapper for [`i18nstrings()`](http://api.lullabot.com/i18nstrings), which is what is used now. The input format is a string, but you can lookup per id, with the special notation the function allows:

```
$term_name = tt('taxonomy:term:'. $term->tid .':name', $term->name);
```

Comment: Thing is that tt() is deprecated and takes a string as the source param :s